# Parents in a directed acyclic graph vs a partial ancestral graph

Tags: causality, graphical-model, graph-theory, causal-diagram

In DAGs, parents are defined as follows:

- A is a parent of B if 'A -> B' edge is in the graph.

In PAGs, there are mixed type of edges, so you can have A -> B, A o-> B. Obviously if A -> B, then A is a parent of B in the PAG, but what if A o-> B?

Is A still considered a parent of B in the PAG, or does the idea of a parent need to be redefined in PAGs?